# Logging out user at session expiry with tank auth & Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, session-timeout, tankauth

I use tank_auth to authenticate and log users in to my application developed using Codeigniter. I noticed that when the session expires after the default period, the user remains logged in. In tank_auth's login() function,

```
if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
```

check at the very beginning always returns true.

I'd like to log the user out when the session expires. Please could you point me in the right direction to implement this?

Thanks!
Mmiz

Comment: when session expires (it is not there) user is logged out automatically (ofc back button works to see data from cache but any other action leads to "not logged in")